# Optimize HTML5 In Android App

Tags: android, html, webview

So I am working on implementing an html5 based game into an android app using webview. Now performance varies but sometimes it is decent or sometimes it is horrible.

So I was wondering if there is some way I can implement some way to optimize the HTML5? Is there an alternative to running HTML5 on android through an apk? Can I enable some sort of acceleration through the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what kind of game you are creating. But HTML5 [is not fully supported](http://html5test.com/results-mobile.html) in Android.

At the moment, I'm working on a porting (from iPad to Android) of an app that is written in HTML5 and JS. I notice that performance in iOS are really greater than the Android's ones. If you want best performance, in my opinion you've got two possibilities:

1) Using another system, based on native API, and not on HTML5

2) Waiting until the performances are improved, and create an App with a min-sdk sufficiently high

Comment: `But HTML5 is not perfectly supported in Android.` You need to greatly qualify this based on android version, manufacturer, and phone model, as well as which browser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I need to know so many things just to even begin to help.

What features are you using that bog your app down?
Canvas?
SVG?
Excessive DOM elements?
Excessive timers and loops?
Are you testing on an emulator or device?

You can create a native app to do just about anything a webview can do and probably be more performance friendly.  It's going to cost you more time and energy, especially if you don't know Java.  It's going to cost you even more time and energy if you ever even think about porting to IOS.  Post the code that is bogging you down and I will let you know if you can optimize it or use some alternative method.